# Using a case statement within an insert into statement

Tags: sql

I try running the below code and I get an error saying

> Unexpected CASE

I am not sure what's wrong with the code. My original table already has 5 columns. It has the Customer id, first name, last name, debt, and accountstatus. I have a blank column called "accountstatus" which I need to fill in using a case statement.

```
INSERT INTO customeraccounts (accountstatus)
    CASE
        WHEN debt = 0 THEN "closed"
        WHEN debt > 0 THEN "open"
        WHEN debt < 0 THEN "refund needed"
    END
```

Comment: It's missing a `SELECT` before the `CASE` (which is an expression, not a statement) -- and it's missing a `FROM` to actually select `debt` from somewhere. Perhaps you meant to `UPDATE` instead, using the `debt` of each row to set `accountstatus`? Depending on your DB system the string literals may also need different quoting (the standard is a single quote, with a double quote reserved for escaping identifiers, though no two engines completely agree on all rules).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I added a SELECT before the CASE. Now it says 'debt' is an invalid identifier. I do have a column named 'debt' in the table.

Comment: Is this what you want ? https://dbfiddle.uk/UtX0xBch

Comment: Yes, per my comment, it's not clear what your desired input and output is. Do you really want to insert new rows, or set the `debt` of existing ones, or maybe you want to add a new column altogether? What does your table look like before and what should it look like after your intended operation? Should `accountstatus` always be based on what `debt` is, even if `debt` changes? In that case a computed column is a better fit.

Comment: @SelVazi My original table already has 5 columns. It has the Customer id, first name, last name, debt, and accountstatus. I have a blank column called "accountstatus" which I need to fill in using a case statement.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have five columns in my table: Customer id, first name, last name, debt, and accountstatus. The accountstatus column is blank so I need to fill it in using a case statement. Based on the customer's debt, my case statement should tell me account status. I want to set the debt of existing ones.

Comment: @ShabMeh Can you update your question by adding this informations that you have shared here

Comment: That's a `case` _expression_, not statement. (A case statement is used in stored procedures for conditoinal execution of code blocks.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fill the **accountstatus** using case statement You can do it as follows :

```
Update customeraccounts
set accountstatus = CASE
  When debt = 0 then "closed"
  When debt > 0 then "open"
  When debt < 0 then "refund needed"
END
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped solve my problem.